# Java OOP array list transfer to another class

Tags: java, oop, jcombobox

I have an array with the below code:

```
    cons_save.savecons();

ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

   idList.add(cons_save.PersonID);
```

When I press the save button the PersonID is suppose to go to this array

```
Person cons_save = new Person();
    cons_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
    cons_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField3.getText());
    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    this.jTextField2.setText("");
    this.jTextField3.setText("");

    cons_save.savecons();

   ArrayList<String> idList = new ArrayList<String>();

   idList.add(cons_save.PersonID);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to get this array list and put it in a drop down list in another form.

When I try to create the drop down list it gives me an error that they symbols for idlist and jcombobox cant be found:

```
String[] array = idList.toArray();
  JComboBox jcombobox1 = new JComboBox(array);
```

In the customer form I have the following code that when  saving it will create a file and get all the fields:

```
Person cust_save = new Person();
    cust_save.setPersonfirstname(this.jTextField1.getText());
    cust_save.setPersonlastname(this.jTextField2.getText());
    cust_save.setPersonID(this.jTextField3.getText());



    this.jTextField1.setText("");
    this.jTextField2.setText("");
    this.jTextField3.setText("");

    cust_save.savecust();
```

That is required is to add the array list to save with these details.

Comment: It is possible. You can use `new JComboBox<String>(idList)`. I don't see the problem

Comment: the problem is when I create the below code, it is saying that both the idList and the jcombobox symbol cant be found:   String[] arr=idList.toArray();
 JComboBox=new JComboBox(arr);

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] arr=idList.toArray();
 JComboBox=new JComboBox(arr);
```

Comment: the problem is that when I create that both idlist and jcombobox is not finding the symbol

Comment: show me more code....where exactly are you using this.....also check with the edit

Comment: I have a save button that when I press it it takes the PersonID and puts it in the idList array. I updated the description with all the code of the save. Then I created a form that have a drop down list. In this form I inputted your code Jcombobox1 is the name of the drop down list. When I input the code both the combobox and the idlist are saying that the symbol cant be found

Comment: When you click save,do you save it in a database?? If not then you need to pass the ArrayList reference i.e. idList to the other form.

Comment: If you do save it in a database, straight away retrieve it from there and put it in the dropdownlist..

Comment: that way works fine but the requirement is that the id goes straight to the customer form

Comment: ya so pass the idList reference to that form

Comment: hehh that is the problem, when passing the idlist to the form its giving me errors

Comment: try adding a few explanations to your code, it'll make it more helpful